# Reference to a reference in c++

Tags: c++

I am going through Reference concepts in c++ and I am little confused by this statement in C++ Complete Reference.

> You cannot reference another reference

So what is happening in this case:

```
    int  var = 10;
    int& ref = var;
    int& r_ref = ref;
    r_ref++;
    cout << "var:" << var << "ref:" << ref << "r_ref:" << r_ref << endl;
```

The output i am getting is:

```
var:11  ref:11  r_ref:11
```

Comment: The code you've written is not a referencing another reference (e.g. `int &&`). You're referencing a variable twice. So, the code is OK.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's slightly confusingly worded. What they mean is that you can't have a `int& &` type (note that there is such thing as a `int&&`, but that's a different type of reference).

In your code, the reference `ref` is referring to the object denoted by `var`. The names `ref` and `var` can be  used interchangeably to refer to the same object. So when you do `int& r_ref = ref;`, you're not making a reference to a reference, but you're making a reference to that same object once again.

Comment: If reference to a reference is considered as int& & then its ok.

Comment: One more thing **we cannot obtain address of a reference variable**. But as ref here refers to var, I am able to print &ref. So can you please explain this.

Comment: @Guarav Yes, when you do `&ref`, you're actually taking the address of the object it refers to. You can't take the address of the reference itself. In fact, it is unspecified whether a reference itself even exists in memory.

Answer (score 8):

> So what is happening in this case:

What is happening is that you are creating another reference `r_ref` to the object referenced by `ref`, which is `var`. So you end up with two references to `var`: `ref` and `r_ref`.

Keep in mind that a reference is just an *alias*: after it is bound to an object (and it *must* be bound to some object at initialization time, and it cannot be re-bound later on), everything you do on the reference is done *on the object being referenced*, as if the 
reference was just an alternative name.

What this statement means:

> You cannot reference another reference

Is that you cannot treat *a reference itself* as an entity that can be further aliased: references are aliases for objects, and whatever you do on a reference (including reference bounding!) is done on the object being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

`int var = 10;` declares a variable `var`. Now when you write `int& ref = var;` defines a reference to `var`. You can look at `ref` as just an alias for `var`. Wherever you use `ref` it's like you would be using `var` directly.

So that's the reason why `int& r_ref = ref;` just defines another reference to `var`.